# swiper.js Navigation and Pagination - wrong position (middle and bottom of site)

Tags: javascript, css, pagination, navigation, swiper.js

I just got started using swiper.js and so far it goes pretty well.

There's only one problem: the pagination bullets and navigation arrows are not positioned correctly.

The arrows are in the middle of the page and the pagination bullets on the bottom of the page (not of the slider container).

I'm sure it's just a little thing that I oversee here (maybe an additional container around the swiper?) - could somebody please help me out here? Thanks!

Here's the HTML section with the slider:

```
<section class="mex-card">
    <div class="swiper swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-ff36">
            <div
              class="swiper-slide-content swiper-carousel-animate-opacity swiper-slide-content-dd9d"
            >
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-c0a7">FREE</div>
      
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-906b">Free plan</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-ff36">
            <div
              class="swiper-slide-content swiper-carousel-animate-opacity swiper-slide-content-dd9d"
            >
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-f04a">$10</div>
      
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-e016">$10 plan</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-ff36">
            <div
              class="swiper-slide-content swiper-carousel-animate-opacity swiper-slide-content-dd9d"
            >
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-f04a">$20</div>
      
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-e016">$20 plan</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-ff36">
            <div
              class="swiper-slide-content swiper-carousel-animate-opacity swiper-slide-content-dd9d"
            >
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-f04a">$30</div>
      
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-e016">$30 plan</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-ff36">
            <div
              class="swiper-slide-content swiper-carousel-animate-opacity swiper-slide-content-dd9d"
            >
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-f04a">$30</div>
      
              <div class="swiper-slide-text swiper-slide-text-e016">$30 plan</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      
     
    
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.mex-card {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    border: 1px solid #dcdfe2;
    border-radius: 0.1875rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* https://studio.swiperjs.com */
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper.min.css);@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/modules/a11y.min.css);@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/modules/navigation.min.css);@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/modules/pagination.min.css);.swiper-carousel{position:relative;margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;overflow:hidden}.swiper-carousel .swiper-slide,.swiper-carousel swiper-slide{position:relative}:root {--swiper-navigation-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 1);--swiper-pagination-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 1);--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 1);}.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 {user-select: none;box-sizing: border-box;overflow: hidden;width: 100%;height: auto;padding: 20px 0px;}.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;width: 100%;height: 100%;position: relative;box-sizing: border-box;}.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide-content {width: 100%;height: 100%;display: flex;position: relative;z-index: 1;box-sizing: border-box;}.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide-ff36 { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);border-radius: 16px;border: 1px solid rgba(189, 189, 189, 1); }.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide-content-dd9d { align-items: flex-start; justify-content: flex-start;flex-direction: column;padding: 48px 32px;gap: 16px; }.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide-text-c0a7 { color: rgba(140, 140, 140, 1);text-align: left;font-size: 24px;line-height: 1.5;font-weight: bold; }.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide-text-906b { color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 1);text-align: left;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.5; }.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide-text-f04a { color: rgba(181, 255, 0, 1);text-align: left;font-size: 24px;line-height: 1.5;font-weight: bold; }.swiper-chocolate-qui-gon-jinn-749 .swiper-slide-text-e016 { color: rgba(181, 255, 0, 1);text-align: left;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.5; }
```

Comment: The structure appears to match https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#swiper-full-html-layout (apart from the order of pagination and button elements, but since those get positioned absolute anyway, that should not matter.) Probably rather some sort of CSS issue, maybe the necessary `position`-ing of the swiper container was overwritten or something. We'd need to a proper [mre] of the issue to be able to check.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).